# Grab snapshot of current active window in C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, abstract

I've been attempting to figure out how to grab a screenshot of my active window. I have read several examples here and other sites, but none of them appear to work for me.

The simplest example I found is:

```
SendKeys::Send("%{PRTSC}");
    Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
    img.Save(".\testprintscreen.jpg");
```

However, it gives me errors 
When hovering the mouse over the img variable it says

> "object of abstract class type "System::Drawing::Image" is not
>   allowed"

and
when hovering the mouse over the Clipboard.GetImage it says

> "type name is not allowed"

Here are my namespace declarations:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Drawing::Imaging;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Globalization;
using System::Math;
```

I have also tried the following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (gcnew Bitmap(this->Width, this->Height));
    Drawing::Rectangle rect = Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    bitmap.Save("TestImage.jpeg", ImageFormat::Jpeg);
```

However that only gives me an image with a black rectangle same shape/size of my program window... it didn't actually capture the contents of the window.

Comment: More information would help. For example, are you working on Windows or Linux? Is the language Java or C++? Are any usual libraries loaded? Stack Overflow offers *tags* you can use for some of these things.

Comment: It's C++, which I assumed was obvious from all the namespace declarations but I didn't know that Java used namespace decs.
Windows as well.

Comment: Being a C++ programmer, I do not know Java. However, I have sometimes initially misidentified Java code as C++ code. This is why I ask. At any rate, it is usual on Stack Overflow to name the language. My platform is Linux, so I will leave this question to others. Good luck.